# How fix Floating Action Button on bottom

Tags: xml, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm making an APP and when users add a product to favorites they can select the products and export to the cart. I'm using a Floating Action Button as the final action to export them, but when I go to the end of the RecyclerView the FAB overwrites the list of products, as you can see. I would like that, when the user goes to the end of the RecyclerView, the FAB is fixed at the end. How can I do this?

Note: I already put the top of the FAB on the bottom of the RecyclerView but it doesn't look good, the RecyclerView ends up being cut.

FavoriteScreen:
[image]

FavoriteScreen with FAB on the bottom of the RecyclerView but it doesn't look good
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without your XMLs it's acutally hard to understand where the problem is, but I'll try hoping you solve this.

I would move the FAB outside the RecyclerView, giving the RecyclerView `android:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf` with your FAB. By doing this you should be able to force the RecyclerView to not go above / under other views.

I had a similar problem too with other views, constraining the RecyclerView like this solved my problem.

If this doesn't sole your problem please, update your question with some XMLs and I will update my answer.